# Stop and uninstall Xcode services

Tags: xcode, cpu, xcode-server

This XCSDeviceService process is always on 25% CPU or more.

[image: terminal screenshot, CPU usage]

I think it's a background service for detecting devices to test on for Xcode Server. I installed Xcode server once on my local machine to test/play around with it. Now I have a second machine for CI, so i don't need it on my local machine anymore. I uninstalled the Server app, but the Xcode services are still running all the time. Also the Xcode Server symbol in the status bar is still there:

[image: Hammer symbol in status bar]

Any ideas how to stop/uninstall the Xcode services?

I installed the server app again and setup Xcode server and turned it off again (I didn't turn Xcode off before uninstalling the server app the last time). That stops the `XCSDeviceService` only for this session. As soon as i log out and in again it restarts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I simply had to remove the whole folder at:

`/Library/Developer/XcodeServer`

Or run this command

```
sudo rm -r /Library/Developer/XcodeServer
```

Then log out and in again.